# Where does PHP finfo() gets its file information? It doesn't match "file -i" output

Tags: php, mime-types

It's annoying, I can't get the correct MIME type for many different files using php finfo().

Here's my little test program:

```
<? $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
echo $finfo->file('/mnt/partage/Film/Sintel.2010.1080p.mkv');
```

Its output is completely incorrect:

```
application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

Here's `file -bi /mnt/partage/Film/Sintel.2010.1080p.mkv` output:

```
video/x-matroska; charset=binary
```

Apparently php finfo() doesn't use the proper magic file. However there aren't many options: either it's `/usr/share/file/magic` or `/etc/magic.mime`, none of them works from php.

I'm running this on Debian stable (wheezy) with backports libmagic. The problem occurs both when calling the program from Apache or the command line.

Comment: You're right: it doesn't use the shared magic lib, the `fileinfo` extension uses its [own libmagic dependency](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/fileinfo/libmagic) just browse the source on github, there's a php script that allows you to re-generate the data_file.c file, using your own mgc file(s), so you could re-compile the extension manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fileinfo uses [data](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/fileinfo/data_file.c) that is compiled with PHP. It does not use libmagic, so changing your libmagic has no effect on PHP. The only option is to use a newer PHP version, or compile it yourself with a new data file.

Edit: or pass the `$magic_file` parameter to [finfo_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php), or set the `MAGIC` environment variable.

Comment: So they really can't get any design decision right... Sigh.

Comment: This is incorrect. PHP can use a custom magic database. The manual states: $magic_file
Name of a magic database file, usually something like /path/to/magic.mime. If not specified, the MAGIC environment variable is used. If the environment variable isn't set, then PHP's bundled magic database will be used. Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

Answer (score 0):

MIME types are not similar on different OS. I am afraid you can't just rely on MIME types. I would suggest to do check on extension or add all possible MIME types for a file type. I had the same issue few weeks ago and I had to rely on extension of the file.

You can try with :

```
$info = pathinfo($file);

echo $info['extension']; //Will be mkv in your case
```

Comment: They are using finfo with PHP, which isn't using a browser to determine MIME type, it will use PHP's magic file.

Comment: Plus, when it comes to web development you need to be careful using extensions over MIME types. Uploading a .gif which is actually a runnable script etc etc.

Comment: @JamesHunt Yeah that's right. That's why I also included the other option to include all possible MIME types for the file.